# Use ng-repeat-start and ng-repeat-end in the same element?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a javascript list `var myElements = [1, 2, 3]` and want to get a string like the following one:

```
<th>
<tr>QC</tr>
<tr>1</tr>
<tr>2</tr>
<tr>3</tr>
</th>
```

As can been seen, the `QC` is not an element in the list but I want to insert that before the `ng-repeat` elements. It seems that I cannot do this by adding `ng-repeat` to the parent element (`<th>`). I tried to use `ng-repeat-start` and `ng-repeat-end` like this:

```
<th>
<tr>QC</tr>
<tr ng-repeat-start="myElement in myElements" ng-repeat-end ng-bind="myElement"></tr>
</th>
```

But it didn't work.(FIXED: it works.. but looks clumsy..)

Does anyone have ideas about how to do this in AngularJS? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried with just `ng-repeat`?

```
<tr>
    <th>QC</th>
    <th ng-repeat="myElement in myElements" ng-bind="myElement"></th>
</tr>
```